# Cannot launch GUI program on Docker container on remote server

Tags: docker, ubuntu, remote-desktop

My working machine in the office is Ubuntu 18.04, and I have installed a Docker container in this machine. Everything works fine, and I can use Graphic User Interface (GUI) programs such as Firefox and PyCharm in the Docker container. When I works at home, I use my Windows 10 notebook, and in order to connect my working machine in the office, I use X2Go program. With this program, I can remotely connect the machine in my office with GUI. I can also run GUI programs remotely. However, when installed Docker container once again remotely, I cannot use GUI programs in the Docker container. The reason is because in order to let the Docker container access host machine's GUI, I use `xhost +` command. However, when running this command remotely, I received the following error:

```
# xhost:  must be on local machine to enable or disable access control.
```

If I ignore this error message, I cannot launch any GUI programs on the Docker container. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article may help:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/remote-install-websphere-application-server-unix-host

In the article:

> If the remote host is not authorized to connect, you can add it to the
>   list of authorized clients using the following command:
>
> xhost +
>
> *xhost: must be on local machine to enable or disable access control.*
>
> This indicates that this command is only authorized from a local
>   console (For example, not within a telnet session).
>
> Next, you must export the display so that GUI screens generated on the
>   remote host will be displayed on the local host. To do this, run the
>   following command on the remote host while logged in through the
>   telnet session from the local host:
>
> export DISPLAY=

Also your Remote Desktop protocol could be an issue.

X2Go uses NX protocol with SSH for security.
NX protocol uses a caching technology which may be part of the the problem.  Remote desktop technologies can vary the experience and may not work with docker GUI remotely.

I have had similar issues with remote desktop technologies (RDP, VNC etc) where some or all of the desktop experience is not visible.

I suggest to try a VNC (RFB protocol) software and see if that works.  RDP is another solution.

Be aware VNC and RDP are not by default very secure unless you use a tunneling solution (VPN etc) and encryption.  There are VNCs with built in encryption (via SSH) and RDP has security solutions also, but if you are accessing it from home to work you should make sure your security manager is aware of the technology you choose that works for you.

Comment: Thanks, and could you suggest some software I can try?

Comment: There is lots of remote desktop software and solutions, i've used TightVNC, TigerVNC, RealVNC.  I have not used many RDP solutions and could not recommend one over another.